# Format email as in python console

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I'm using jinja2 to send a string by email. I have got everything working, except that I can't figure out how to maintain the same format I get when printing out that string in the console.

The string I get in the console is exactly this one:

```
TAF LEVX 241700Z 2418/2518 23009KT 3000 -DZ BR BKN010 BKN020 TX11/2514Z TN08/2506Z 
  TEMPO 2418/2518 1200 -DZ BCFG BKN004 
  TEMPO 2418/2518 0800 DZ BCFG 
  TEMPO 2418/2518 0350 FG BKN003 PROB30 
  TEMPO 2418/2518 30010KT 7000 NSW BKN020 
  TEMPO 2418/2518 0150 FG BKN001
```

But then, when I add

```
<p></p>
```

I get the email with all lines attached, as in:

```
TAF LEVX 241700Z 2418/2518 23009KT 3000 -DZ BR BKN010 BKN020 TX11/2514Z TN08/2506Z TEMPO     2418/2518 1200 -DZ BCFG BKN004 TEMPO 2418/2518 0800 DZ BCFG TEMPO 2418/2518 0350 FG BKN003 PROB30 TEMPO 2418/2518 30010KT 7000 NSW BKN020 TEMPO 2418/2518 0150 FG BKN001
```

Needless to say that I'm not an expert in jinja2 or HTML, that's why I'm looking for help.

Is there an easy way to keep the format?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could just `.replace('\n', '</br>')` before you send off the email.

Comment: ^thats your answer ...

Comment: @sundance shouldn't it be `<br/>`?

Comment: I think `<br>`, `</br>` and `<br/>` are equivalent on all modern browsers. I do wonder what the officially accepted way to do it is, though. I use them interchangeably.

Comment: Since it's a self-closing tag, `<br />` is the syntactically correct form.

Comment: Using `<br>` won't preserve indentation, so it is not a perfect solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it does work but without indentation as RobertT said... it still is a good solution anyway!

Comment: @sundance `</br>` alone is invalid syntax. It works sometimes only because some browser are trying to silently fix it by interpreting it as regular `<br>` but it's not a guaranteed behaviour. Regular HTML5 advices using `<br>` but accepts `<br/>` for XHTML1.1 compatibility. For completeness: HTML5 in its XHTML serialization expects `<br/>` or `<br></br>` syntax, where latter one might be used as long as proper mime type is provided (which hardly anyone does), but it's not encouraged as without mime type some browsers will 'fix it' in their HTML parser and all such `<br>`s will get doubled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I finally found the answer to this.

As it turns out, I had to use **both proposed solutions** to get it right:

1. First I had to replace the string by doing

   ```
   .replace("\n", "<br />")
   ```

   To answer what was being discussed from sundance's response, it has to be `<br />`, as `</br>` won't work (at least when sending an html email).

   This basically creates the new lines, with no indentation.
2. In order to get the indentation right we need to use `<pre></pre>` as suggested by RobertT (but only after applying point one, as we do not get the line returns with this).

Thanks everyone once again for the help!

Edit: I'm using jinja2 to output the HTML, Mailgun to send the email and I'm using a Gmail account for testing.

Comment: Hmm that's quite strange, as `pre` should preserve line endings by default. To solve why it isn't happening I would probably need to know using what module and function calls are you sending results via email and  what email client are you using for verification? I have some suspicions that your mail sending code isn't converting `[LF]` to `[CR][LF]` or something like that and that's why part of formatting gets lost.

Comment: Yeah that's strange, I would think `<pre>` with line breaks (`\n`, not `<br />`) would do it. Glad you found an answer, though!

Answer (score 2):

What about `<p style="white-space: pre">`. That should preserve your original formatting. Or simply use `<pre></pre>` instead of `<p></p>` for clarity.

Comment: Thank you! If I just use this I get the white spaces right, but the string comes out in one long line.